# background colors render to word document in rmd but not qmd

Tags: r, gt

If you render the below in an rmarkdown document, colors appear in the color column just fine when you output to DOCX.

In a quarto document however the background colors do not display.

I cannot tell if this is a bug in my code, or if it is something with `gt()` package.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

df_text <- tibble::tibble(index = c("C-1", "C-2"),
                          finding = c("A finding.", "Another finding."),
                          color = c("red", "blue")) 

df_text %>% 
  gt::gt() %>% 
  gt::tab_style(
    style = gt::cell_fill(color = "red"),
    locations = gt::cells_body(
      column = color,
      rows = stringr::str_detect(color, "red")
    )
  ) %>% 
  gt::tab_style(
    style = gt::cell_fill(color = "blue"),
    locations = gt::cells_body(
      column = color,
      rows = stringr::str_detect(color, "blue")
    )
  )
```

Comment: Do you want do it in quarto and which output format?

Comment: Hi @manro, preference is quarto and DOCX. 

Equal parts demonstration to my management, building for posterity since rmarkdown will eventually be depricated, and YAML controls that more gracefully handle screenshot of a DT I'm including in both HTML and DOCX versions.

Comment: Hi. Don't afraid, Rmarkdown is staying with us ;) https://yihui.org/en/2022/04/quarto-r-markdown/ I'll see your example now,, wait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you can do it in this way.

Save the gt table in your favourite image format and after simply include:

**An example:**

````
---
format: docx
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

df_text <- tibble::tibble(index = c("C-1", "C-2"),
                          finding = c("A finding.", "Another finding."),
                          color = c("red", "blue")) 

df_text %>% 
  gt::gt() %>% 
  gt::tab_style(
    style = gt::cell_fill(color = "red"),
    locations = gt::cells_body(
      column = color,
      rows = stringr::str_detect(color, "red")
    )
  ) %>% 
  gt::tab_style(
    style = gt::cell_fill(color = "blue"),
    locations = gt::cells_body(
      column = color,
      rows = stringr::str_detect(color, "blue")
    )
  ) %>%
  gtsave("tab_to_word.png")
```

![]("tab_to_word.png")
````

**Output:**

[image]

---

**An addition:**

*If one method doesn't work - try another one.* `flextable`

````
---
format: docx

---

```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(flextable)
library(tidyverse)

df_text <- tibble::tibble(index = c("C-1", "C-2"),
                          finding = c("A finding.", "Another finding."),
                          color = c("red", "blue")) 
ft_1 <- flextable(df_text) %>%
  autofit()


ft_1 <- bg(ft_1, i = 1, j = 3, bg="red")

ft_1 <- bg(ft_1, i = 2, j = 3, bg="blue")

ft_1

```
````

[image]

Now this table can be edited.

Comment: This is a nice workaround, thanks. One of the attractive things about using `gt` and printing to DOCX was the ability for others to edit the table in DOCX if needed. I'll have to trade this off before migrating back from quarto to rmarkdown.

Comment: @M.Wood do you want just a table, not a pic?

Comment: @M.Wood Look to an addition